# Dojo Grid not displaying properly

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I'm using a datagrid/table construct and the data is appearing over the column headers and two check boxes are appearing.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "StyleSheet.css";
    @import "js/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/pfga/pfga.css";
    @import "js/dojotoolkit/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
    @import "js/dojotoolkit/dojox/resources/Grid.css";
    @import "js/dojotoolkit/dojox/resources/tundraGrid.css";
    .dojoxGrid table {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script src="common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojox.data.XmlStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.date");

    var pageRef = 'l_events'; 
</script>
```

```
    <div id="pagehead" class="Heading1" >Upcoming Range Events - PF&amp;GA</div>

    <input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" store="monthStore" searchAttr="month" name="month" id="monthInput" class="pfga" />
    <br />
    <div id="grid" style="width:600px; overflow:visible; height:800px">
        <table id="eventGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="width:600px; " store="eventStore" class="tundra">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="date">Date</th>
                    <th field="description">Description</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" field="time">Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have the tundra class on the whole body of your page?  Or just the grid div?

Comment: Tundra is just being used in the Grid div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem was a simple Path to the Grid and tundraGrid css files. Fixed that, solved the issue.

Comment: How did you find out that it was a path problem? We are facing the same issue here. Any help?

Comment: Request you to post the changes to your code, so that it would be helpful for us and future readers.

Comment: I'd exhausted every other possibility so I was looking at it line by line. I was missing the grid part of the path.

@import "js/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
@import "js/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css";